# How can I execute all the tasks of the queue and not only a number equal to the number of workers?

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, fortran, gdb, openmp

I am trying to run a number of tasks stored in a queue called `master_queue` using worker threads. The condition is that the number of workers is smaller than the number of tasks to execute. In order to do this, each worker thread creates a queue of its own called `thread_queue` and will therefore receive tasks from the `master_queue`.

```
if ((num_thread  .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then ! ONLY WORKERS 
       if (nthreads-2 .le. last_task-first_task+1) then ! condition:  workers less than tasks 
          call queue_create(thread_queue,last_task-first_task+1) !< create a thread queue of capacity 1
          do             
             call OMP_set_lock(lck)  !< set the lock
             if (.not. queue_empty(master_queue)) then !< if the queue is not empty
                call queue_enqueue_data(thread_queue,master_queue%data(1),success) !< add the first element of the list to the thread queue
                call queue_dequeue_data(master_queue) !< retire the first element of the master queue
             end if
             call OMP_unset_lock(lck) !< unset the lock
    
             call thread_queue%data(1)%f_ptr(self,var) !< execute the one and only element of the thread queue

             call queue_dequeue_data(thread_queue) !< retire the element
             if (queue_empty(master_queue)) EXIT
          end do
          call queue_destroy(thread_queue)  !< destroy the thread queue 
       end if
    end if
```

I have set an infinite loop so that I can run all the tasks. We leave the loop when the queue `master_queue` becomes empty (no tasks to execute) : `if (queue_empty(master_queue)) EXIT`.

When I run my program, I get a segmentation fault.
Output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f8ab4a2d700 in ???
#1  0x7f8ab4a2c8a5 in ???
#0  0x7f8ab4a2d700 in ???
#2  0x7f8ab46cc20f in ???
#1  0x7f8ab4a2c8a5 in ???
#3  0x0 in ???
#2  0x7f8ab46cc20f in ???
#3  0x0 in ???
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

These are the flags I used to compile:  `-O3 -g -fcheck=all -fopenmp` 
I use `gfortran` to compile.

When I use `gdb`, I get:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/hakim/stage_hecese_HPC/OpenMP/hecese_OMP/Brouillons/output_hecese_omp 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff78d7700 (LWP 22706)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff70d6700 (LWP 22707)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff68d5700 (LWP 22708)]

Thread 3 "output_hecese_o" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff70d6700 (LWP 22707)]
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000055555555a072 in master_worker::master_worker_execution (self=..., var=..., tasks_ready_master=..., first_task=<optimized out>, last_task=<optimized out>, nthreads=4, num_thread=2, lck=0, 
    thread_queue=<optimized out>, master_queue=0x5555555b02a0) at master_worker_test.f90:67
#2  0x000055555555ad88 in management::__app_management_MOD_management._omp_fn.0 () at test.f90:111
#3  0x00007ffff7b77a86 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff78e3609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#5  0x00007ffff7a8c293 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

The line 67 in the file `master_worker_test` is:

```
call thread_queue%data(1)%f_ptr(self,var) !< execute the one and only element of the thread queue
```

Using `valgrind`, I get:

```
==22788== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22788== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22788== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22788== Command: ./output_hecese_omp
==22788== 
==22788== Thread 4:
==22788== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==22788==    at 0x0: ???
==22788==    by 0x10E071: __master_worker_MOD_master_worker_execution (master_worker_test.f90:67)
==22788==    by 0x10ED87: __app_management_MOD_management._omp_fn.0 (test.f90:111)
==22788==    by 0x4C8BA85: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==22788==    by 0x4F1D608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==22788==    by 0x4DD7292: clone (clone.S:95)
==22788==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22788== 

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x4888700 in ???
#1  0x48878a5 in ???
#2  0x4cfb20f in ???
#3  0x0 in ???
==22788== 
==22788== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22788==    at 0x4CFB169: raise (raise.c:46)
==22788==    by 0x4CFB20F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so)
==22788== 
==22788== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22788==     in use at exit: 264,924 bytes in 115 blocks
==22788==   total heap usage: 188 allocs, 73 frees, 331,516 bytes allocated
==22788== 
==22788== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22788==    definitely lost: 29,120 bytes in 1 blocks
==22788==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22788==      possibly lost: 912 bytes in 3 blocks
==22788==    still reachable: 234,892 bytes in 111 blocks
==22788==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22788== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22788== 
==22788== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==22788== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Note: When I comment `do ... end do` (the loop), the program runs normally.

**EDIT:** If I replace, inside the `do` loop, `if (queue_empty(master_queue)) then` by `if (.not. queue_empty(master_queue)) then`, the program runs normally too. As if the `master_queue` can't get empty .. I'm confused..

Any help, please ?

Comment: Re, "In order to do this, each worker thread creates a queue of its own..." That seems overly complicated. In a simplistic thread pool, there is just one queue, and each worker loops, taking just _one_ task from the queue, then performing the task, then going back to the top of the loop to get the next task.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm not sure if I understand well your comment .. What I mean by this is that each worker thread creates a variable of type "queue" declared as a private variable (in the `OMP PARALLEL` construct). The queue variable contains mostly a vector of tasks and a capacity.I have implemented it in a module which contains the definition of the queue structure as well as the functions enqueue, dequeue, create,destroy...

Comment: I'm not trying to answer what went wrong with your program. I'm not qualified to talk about whatever libraries you are calling from your Fortran code. I'm just saying that if you have "worker threads" performing tasks that come from a "master queue," then that sounds like a [_thread pool_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). But, I've never heard of a thread pool in which each worker had its own _private_ queue. That sounds overly complicated to me. OTOH, maybe it's a necessary complication: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I tried to do this directly by using `OMP TASK` but I got a very bad performance.. I'm trying to implement what `OMP TASK` does from scratch by defining a thread queue for each thread and by scheduling the tasks (I don't know if it's the same thing as the thread pool but I think it is)..

Comment: In gdb, can you go to `frame 1` and then `p thread_queue%data(1)%f_ptr` ? Maybe it’s zero.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I get `$1 = (PTR TO -> ( void () (REF TO -> ( Type __class_tasks_Tcb_t ), REF TO -> ( Type variables )) )) 0x0`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick this how `fptr` is declared : `procedure(my_interface),NOPASS,pointer:: f_ptr => null() !< the function pointer`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I added an `!$OMP BARRIER` after unsetting the lock. Now I get a new error message: `Fortran runtime error: Pointer actual argument 'master_queue' is not associated` at the line `if (queue_empty(master_queue)) EXIT `

Comment: Can you show us the portion of your code where fptr is assigned something other than null() ? Maybe it's not reachable for some reason.